# Get c# classes after a program is compiled

Tags: c#, .net, class, attributes, compiled

I have a program that I am making for a friend and I don't want him to see the whole code, but I want him to be able to add classes that have attributes on the classes so he can add his own stuff to it, how would I be able to get classes using a compiled program and add them to the dictionary of methods to be called upon later?

Comment: search for "C# plug-in" or "C# MEF"

Comment: Couldn't you just compile the code and hand him the DLLs?

Comment: Most realistic option is to write such bad code that noone want to look at it :). Otherwise Reflector/ILSpy (or any other IL disassembler) will show perfectly readable code...

Comment: Try to create a class library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx).

> The Managed Extensibility Framework or MEF is a library for creating
>   lightweight, extensible applications. It allows application developers
>   to discover and use extensions with no configuration required. It also
>   lets extension developers easily encapsulate code and avoid fragile
>   hard dependencies. MEF not only allows extensions to be reused within
>   applications, but across applications as well.